# javascript injection in uiwebview iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios5, uiwebview, ios6

I create one of the app that uses uiwebview.

I use JavaScript injection after uiwebview finished loading.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').item[0].font = 'custom font';
```

The custom font is already added into the project.

That code work fine on iOS5, it change the whole web page font to the custom font.

ISSUES:

1) It can't change 15% of web page text on iOS6 uiwebview. I don't understand why. Because of iOS6. But why does it work on iOS5?

Please suggest me any way,
Thanks for your help.